# Visual Studio - vdproj is incompatible

Tags: visual-studio

I have a project in a solution I am working on in Visual Studio 2012, and I get this message for one of the projects: "This version of Visual Studio does not have the following project types installed, or does not support them." It is a vdproj. What does this mean and how do I resolve this problem

Answer (score 69, accepted):

[vdproj](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/buckh/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs/) is a [MSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) creation project for Visual Studio.  Its been deprecated and most people have moved on to either [WIX](http://wixtoolset.org/) or [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) or a professional grade installer creation tools such as Install Shield.

If you do not require an installer for your product just exclude the vdproj project from the solution and continue with your life

for fun if you want to try to transition right away to wix, try this powershell script https://github.com/chrisoldwood/vdproj2wix

Comment: InnoSetup is also a great and simple installer framework.

Comment: This should not be marked as the correct answer John Pittaway has provided a link in his comment to the required installer for 2017 - I installed this and my vdproject is working as expected again

Comment: Yes, John Pittaway's answer worked for me as well. Also, for VS 2015, there was a different extension that was called "Visual Studio Setup and Deployment Projects" which worked for me for several years.

Comment: It's still a good choice for simple installers which don't warrant the near vertical learning curve of Wix.

Comment: @BozoJoe Can vdproj be excluded easily?

Comment: @Sidso sure, remove it from the sln

Answer (score 230):

The correct procedure to resolve "Incompatible" issue with VDPROJ Projects coming from **Visual Studio 2010 and 2015** in 2017, 2019 or 2022 is:

1. Enter Visual Studio .NET 2017, 2019 or 2022
2. - **2017:** Click on **"Tools"** -> **Extension and Updates** -> **Online**
   - **2019 or higher:** Click on **"Extensions"** -> **Manage Extensions** -> **Online**
3. Type **"Installer Project"** on the search box
4. Click on "Install" in **Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project**
5. Restart Visual Studio .NET and follow the instructions to install the extension
6. Right click on the projects which have "Incompatible" and click "reload" (tested in VS2022).

With this extension the old project (2010, 2015) is capable to work in (2017, 2019, 2022). VDPROJ are not deprecated, simply they are improved with a new extension, for more information about this please visit the oficial [MarketPlace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects).

Comment: I had to do a "Reload Project" after installing the extension before the "Incompatible" project designation would go away on VS2019.

Comment: Now under "Extensions" -> "Manage Extensions"

Comment: This doesn't work. After installing and enabling, VDPROJ projects are still "incompatible".

Comment: Works as of Feb 2021 :)

Comment: Works for me too. Close Visual Studio and install extension then start visual studio again. After properly start VS, open your solution. In case your setup project excluded then include it in solution.

Comment: Can confirm it works, you need to right click on the projects which have "Incompatible" and click "reload".

Comment: Extensions -> Manage Extensions. Make sure the VSIX window doesn't get hidden behind other windows. Close VS, install the extension, start VS. Reload project.

Comment: After about 6 months I had the same issue; it was still installed under the Extensions but was disabled. Re-enabled, Re-started VS, Re-loaded the project and all worked again.

Comment: It's also working for Visual Studio 2022.
Extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2022InstallerProjects
Then reload project as MZB noted

Comment: Works as of April/2023 with Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 Preview. Remember you need to right click on the projects which have "Incompatible" and click "reload".

Answer (score 74):

There is also the official:

- [Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9)
- [Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Installer Projects](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d)
- [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)  (2017 & 2019)
- [Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2022InstallerProjects)

if you can jump to VS 2013, 2015, 2017+2019, or 2022

But BozoJoe is right, its time to drop vdproj and move on to WiX.

Comment: Fixed my issue temporarily, but then about 6 months later for no discernible reason my install projects all went back to being incompatible.  Reinstalling has not helped.

Comment: This should be marked as answer. Thank you, works flawlessly

Comment: Installer projects do not work in VS anymore. Looks like they removed compatibility in 16.0.1

Comment: I'm running VS 2019 version 16.6.3 and the extension version 0.9.8 and I can load my legacy-style installer projects - maybe there is something wrong with your .vdproj or Visual Studio installation?

Comment: Microsoft just released version 0.9.9 of this extension (2020/09/16) so the .vdproj is not quite as "dead" as we might think.

Answer (score 47):

Visual Studio 2017 can use the Visual Studio Installer. It is NOT a default. You have to run *InstallerProjects.vsix*. You can get it at [Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects). I have used it and worked great, at least for a windows GUI project. It's worth a shot before you get into the Install Shield intricacies.

Comment: This one now also has Visual Studio 2019 support

Comment: This is the most valid answer to the problem/question, it works for VS 2017 and VS 2019. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

if You use Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project  (Vs2017).
Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project may be disabled after an update.

- Tools -> Extensions and Updates..
- Click Installed
- Find and Select -> Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project
- do Enable
- Restart Visual Studio

Comment: Now under "Extensions" -> "Manage Extensions"

Answer (score 1):

Just Download the new extension for **Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project** to work.

Answer (score 1):

visual studio 2022:

If you have the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project extension already added to your project, also make sure its enabled.

Extensions -> Manage Extensions -> Installed -> Find the installer project on the list and if it says "Enable", click on it, this should enable it.