# VS 2022 can not open .NET 4.7 C# solution on a newly installed Windows 11 machine

Tags: c#, .net, version, visual-studio-2022, target-platform

I'm trying to open a C# solution with target Framework .NET 4.7 on a newly installed Windows 11 machine with VS 2022.

When opening the solution, the following message is displayed:

[image]

I the target version can not be changed.

I tried to install .NET 4.7.2 from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks?cid=getdotnetsdk), reopen the solution, tut the same message is displayed.

`dotnet --info` command line result:

```
.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.304
 Commit:    7e794e2806

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.22621
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-arm64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.304\

Host:
  Version:      7.0.7
  Architecture: arm64
  Commit:       5b20af47d9

.NET SDKs installed:
  7.0.304 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.18 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.18 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.18 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Other architectures found:
  x64   [C:\Program Files\dotnet\x64]
    registered at [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\InstallLocation]
  x86   [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet]
    registered at [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x86\InstallLocation]

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

`reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP" /s` command line result:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\CDF

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\CDF\v4.0
    HttpNamespaceReservationInstalled    REG_DWORD    0x1
    NetTcpPortSharingInstalled    REG_DWORD    0x1
    NonHttpActivationInstalled    REG_DWORD    0x1
    SMSvcHostPath    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
    WMIInstalled    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client
    CBS    REG_DWORD    0x1
    Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
    InstallPath    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
    Release    REG_DWORD    0x82348
    Servicing    REG_DWORD    0x0
    TargetVersion    REG_SZ    4.0.0
    Version    REG_SZ    4.8.09032

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client\1033
    CBS    REG_DWORD    0x1
    Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
    Release    REG_DWORD    0x82348
    Servicing    REG_DWORD    0x0
    TargetVersion    REG_SZ    4.0.0
    Version    REG_SZ    4.8.09032

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full
    CBS    REG_DWORD    0x1
    Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
    InstallPath    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
    Release    REG_DWORD    0x82348
    Servicing    REG_DWORD    0x0
    TargetVersion    REG_SZ    4.0.0
    Version    REG_SZ    4.8.09032

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\1033
    CBS    REG_DWORD    0x1
    Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
    Release    REG_DWORD    0x82348
    Servicing    REG_DWORD    0x0
    TargetVersion    REG_SZ    4.0.0
    Version    REG_SZ    4.8.09032

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4.0
    (Default)    REG_SZ    deprecated

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4.0\Client
    Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
    Version    REG_SZ    4.0.0.0
```

Please advise

Comment: The dialog actually **offers** to download and install the proper .NET framework version (second option) - have you tried that? And btw: the `dotnet` command line tool is **only** for .NET Core frameworks - it does **NOT** show/handle/detect the "old" full .NET frameworks installed or present

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76416772/10024425

Answer (score 0):

"I tried to install .net 4.7.2 from here" - install 4.7 https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net47-web-installer

Answer (score 0):

In the direction of @Tudeschizieuinchid answer.
Trying to install v4.7 AFTER 4.8 was isntalled (as part of the vs installation), fails.

The way is to modify visual studio 2022 installation (or actually do it during the initial process).

Select `.NET Framework 4.6.2-4.7.1 development tools` option

[image]

Comment: If you found the referenced post helpful, then consider upvoting it so that it's easier for others to find, as well.