# Problem when creating project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a problem when creating a project in Visual Studio.

I have followed all the default steps, when I create the project the project folder is not included in the solution and it says that there are 0 projects, therefore it does not let me compile or do anything.

I have tried reinstalling and nothing... Can anyone help me?

Comment: _Can anyone help me?_: Not unless you provide detailed steps of the actions that you've taken.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76416772/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/76250905/10024425

Comment: Please feel free to let know if you have any question.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, there are 0 projects in Solution Explorer, something like this:

[image]

I changed the path of dotnet in the environment variable, so this situation occurred. In short, there is a problem with the path of dotnet in the current environment variable. However, the dotnet path error usually does not occur when installing Visual Studio. This error is usually caused by the fact that there are two dotnet paths in the environment variables at the same time.

**Cause Analysis:**

Your system should have both x86 and x64 dotnet sdk installed, respectively. C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet and C:\Program Files\dotnet.

**Solution:**

You can modify the environment variables and find the path "This PC -> Right click 'Properties' -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables –> System variables –> double click path". Delete "C:\Program Files (x86) \dotnet" and make sure there is "C:\Program Files\dotnet".

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]